No hot water to Dishwasher
New one handle faucet installed which works fine but no hot water to dishwasher. I followed water line from dishwasher to hot water connection under sink and turned the valve both ways but do not get any water in the dishwasher. Worked fine before we installed new faucet.

Pictures of the connections will help, but a faucet itself should be a separate valve and should not interfere with the dishwasher.  Possible a problem with the dishwasher that just happen at the same time as replacing the faucet.

So you get no water to the d/w—neither hot nor cold?

Check to see if you have a "Floodsafe" line connected to the dishwasher.  It may have done it's job and closed the line thinking there was a leak.
